# Get value from text area

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

How can I get the value from a textarea field when it's not equal to ""?

I tried this code, but when I enter text into the textarea the alert() it doesn't work.

How do I fix it?

```
<textarea name="textarea" placeholder="Enter the text..."></textarea>

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("textarea").value !== "") {
        alert($("textarea").value);
    }
  
});
```

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `.value` property.

Comment: Have you tried .val() ?

Comment: Javascript is .value, and Jquery is .val()

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `.val()` to get value of textarea and use `$.trim()` to empty spaces.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.trim($("textarea").val()) != "") {
        alert($("textarea").val());
    }
});
```

Or, Here's what I would do for clean code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var val = $.trim($("textarea").val());
    if (val != "") {
        alert(val);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jVUsZ/

Comment: This is jQuery specific maybe the question is missing some tag ^^

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy missing tag? Please see the question again for the ** `textarea` tag**. I gave jQuery answer because OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 250):

### Vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById("textareaID").value
```

### jQuery

```
$("#textareaID").val()
```

---

Cannot do the other way round (it's always good to know what you're doing)

```
document.getElementById("textareaID").value() // --> TypeError: Property 'value' of object #<HTMLTextAreaElement> is not a function
```

jQuery:

```
$("#textareaID").value // --> undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').val();
```

`textarea.value` would be pure JavaScript, but here you're trying to use JavaScript as a not-valid jQuery method (`.value`).

Answer (score 0):

use the val() method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var j = $("textarea");
    if (j.val().length > 0) {
        alert(j.val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `.val()` not `.value`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("textarea").val() != "") {
    alert($("textarea").val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for a code that doesn't use jQuery. I was searching for this for so long and i had to "debug" it my self in order to find how to get the value of textarea without using jQuery.
Well here is your solution:
document.getElementsByClassName('textarea')[0].value

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()`:

```
 if ($("textarea").val()!== "") {
        alert($("textarea").val());
    }
```