# document.getElementById doesn't get newly entered HTML text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following code.

The idea is to print the contents of the div with name "PrintThis" which incorporates the text input area "textarea1".

The problem is that getElementById only ever returns the string loaded with the page; "cake" in this case.

If I change "cake" to "pie" by clicking and typing into "textarea1" on the page then printContents still has "cake" not "pie".

```
<html> 
<head> </head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function printFunction(divName) {
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
//Now call a script to print (not included)
}
</script>
 <body> 
  <div id="printThis" name="printThis">
   <textarea id="textarea1" cols="1" rows="10" style="width:95%!important;" ">cake</textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Print Div" onClick="printFunction('printThis')">
</body></html>
```

In my production version I also use AJAX to post the text area value back to the server, so could in theory use a page refresh, though that doesn't run, I tried using these options.

```
document.location.reload(true);
window.top.location=window.top.location;
```

The production version does have jQuery available too.

Comment: Try to get value with jquery val() function...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14939010/1700321.

Comment: OK, I will take a look at jQuery option, but bear in mind in the production version, printThis Div will have multiple elements.

Comment: I think what you want is the same as:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818395/how-to-get-form-html-via-jquery-including-updated-value-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you are trying to get innerHTML of the div, instead of the actual textarea.
secondly instead of trying to get innerHTML try using value.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdymvjz8/

```
<div id="printThis" name="printThis">
   <textarea id="textarea1" cols="1" rows="10">cake</textarea>
  </div>
<input type="button" value="PrintDiv" onClick="printFunction('textarea1')">

function printFunction(divName) {
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).value;
}
```

Comment: See my comment to user1371641, again sorry if it wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: Before accessing innerHTML of the div you can first get the value of its children and update their innerHTML before getting value of the div. I have updated the fiddle, do check it out.  

`function printFunction(divName) {
    textArea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
textArea.innerHTML = textArea.value;
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    alert(printContents);
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are having multiple items in your div in production then you can iterate through the children of the div and drag out the values.

```
function printFunction(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName),
    childItemCount = 0,
    stringToPrint = '';

 for (childItemCount; childItemCount < printContents.children.length; childItemCount++) {
    stringToPrint += printContents.children[childItemCount].value;
 }

 console.log(stringToPrint);
 //Now call a script to print (not included)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access the whole of the 'printThis' DIV in the production version. The example given in the question is simplified. Sorry if this isn't clear and thank you for your answer.

Comment: And you can of course use innerHTML for DOM elements that does not reflect anything on the value property (label, span...).