# Submit button with textbox and JS

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to create a textbox with a submitt button, and then store the data in the textbox into a js variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939010/get-value-from-text-area)

Comment: @FastSnail They are also wondering about how to code the HTML, not just the JS with existing HTML... Also I love it when something is marked as a duplicate of a duplicate 

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [HTML forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and then take the `value` attribute using JavaScript:

```js
var myValue;
function submit() {
  myValue = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
  console.log(myValue);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:submit()">
  <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The final value is contained in the `myValue` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//get value in console log
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault()
console.log(a.value)
})
//or get value in specific div
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault()
document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = a.value;
})
```

```html
<form>
<textarea></textarea>
 <input type="submit">
 <br/>
</form>
 <div id='val'></div>
```