# How To Retrieve the Value of a textarea

Tags: html, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to access the text inside of a text area using cheerio , but its text is not shown in the HTML Dom .

this is the HTML of the text area:

```
<textarea id="MainContentPlaceHolder_txtGtin-inputEl" name="MainContentPlaceHolder_txtGtin" rows="4" cols="20" readonly="readonly" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-textarea" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

and this is a picture of the text area in the browser:

[image]

i guess its some sort of server generated text that doesn't show up in the Dom ( is it? ).

how can i get the text from the HTML of the page and inside the code?

I'm Using Puppeteer + cheerio to scrape the page , if you know any way to help me with this in either one id be thankful .

Comment: The value of the textarea isn't stored between it's opening and closing tags once it is part of the DOM, that text is used to set the initial value of the property which actually holds the value. You should be able to get the value of a textarea in the same way as an input https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790446/1650337

Comment: i know that , when i try to use cheerio's ``` .val() ``` function to get the value of the textarea , it returns  undefined , guess i need to use something else.

Comment: Sounds like it, if the question is about retrieving the value, you may want to edit the question/title to make it clearer and add some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @hardkoded anything i could think of , waiting a few more  seconds if the content is still being loaded ,  ant trying to access it with puppeteer's evaluate()  function , but i was unccessfull

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the text content is being added by JavaScript after the page has loaded. You may need to wait a second or two after the loaded event is detected by Puppeteer before you fetch the content.

Also, check whether that text is added using a `placeholder` attribute rather than standard DOM content.